# addeventlistener callback - get an element inside the callback return null

Tags: javascript

I've got this code:

```js
possibilities.forEach((possibility) => {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("p-3", "cursor-pointer");
    let { label, postcode, city } = possibility.properties;
    li.innerText = label;
    li.addEventListener("click", () => fillZipAndCityInput(postcode, city));
    $list.appendChild(li);
  });
```

Here the callback:

```js
function fillZipAndCityInput(zip, city) {
  const zipInput = document.getElementById("zip");
  const cityInput = document.getElementById("city");

  zipInput.value = zip;
  cityInput.value = city;

  console.log(document.querySelector(".possibilities"));
  // => null
}
```

But if I modify the code to:

```js
// code 
li.addEventListener("click", function () {
   fillZipAndCityInput(postcode, city, this);
});
// code

function fillZipAndCityInput(zip, city, ctx) {
  const zipInput = document.getElementById("zip");
  const cityInput = document.getElementById("city");

  zipInput.value = zip;
  cityInput.value = city;

  ctx.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

it's working. But why? Of course with arrow function I cannot access to context without binding. But here, I don't know why it's not working in both cases: when I get HTML Element inside the callback and also when I get the HTML Element outside but I call the constant inside the callback. I hope I'm enough clear, don't hesitate for more code. Thanks a lot!

Edit: here the HTML part:

```html
<div class="possibilties absolute bottom-100 left-0">
   <ul class="list bg-slate-400 rounded text-white divide-y"> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you have no elements with class containing `possibilities` - I’m not seeing any in your code.

Comment: Hi James, indeed I didn't paste the HTML part. The post has been edited. But the response is : yes, I've got this class on HTML element

Comment: Looks like there’s a typo in possibilities

Comment: Damn, you right! Shame on me.. Never coding after the evening 